# How to convert parquet-go []interface{} to slice of structs?

Tags: go, parquet

I am working on reading parquet file as shown below. Below code read parquet file and converts them to `ParquetProduct` struct which I use it later on to get data out of it.

```
func (r *clientRepository) read(logg log.Prot, file string, bucket string) error {
    var err error
    fr, err := pars3.NewS3FileReader(context.Background(), bucket, file, r.s3Client.GetSession().Config)
    if err != nil {
        return errs.Wrap(err)
    }
    defer xio.CloseIgnoringErrors(fr)

    pr, err := reader.NewParquetReader(fr, nil, int64(r.cfg.Workers))
    if err != nil {
        return errs.Wrap(err)
    }

    if pr.GetNumRows() == 0 {
        logg.Infof("Skipping %s due to 0 rows", file)
        return nil
    }

    for {
        rows, err := pr.ReadByNumber(r.cfg.RowsToRead)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }
        if len(rows) <= 0 {
            break
        }

        // doing Marshal here first
        byteSlice, err := json.Marshal(rows)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }

        var productRows []ParquetProduct
        // and then Unmarshal here
        err = json.Unmarshal(byteSlice, &productRows)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }

        //.....
        // use productRows here
        //.....
    
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Problem Statement**

I am doing `Marshal` first and then `Unmarshalling` to get the required object. Is there any way to avoid all this. `ReadByNumber` function (of `parquet-go` library) returns `[]interface{}` so is there anyway to get my `[]ParquetProduct` struct back just from the `[]interface{}`?

I am using `go 1.19`. This is the library I am using to read `parquet` file - https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go

Is there any better and efficient way to do this overall?

Comment: Probably you want to pass an instance of your `DesiredType` as the `obj` parameter instead of just `nil` to the `NewParquetReader` func. That's then used to resolve the element type of the slice and is then also used to construct the slice. Then you can convert the interface slice to a slice of your `DesiredType` using per-element type assertion.

Comment: can you provide an example on how will I do this? @mkopriva it looks like an interesting approach which I missed it earlier I guess. Do I need to pass `ParquetProduct{}` instead of `nil`? Any example with my current code will help me understand better.

Comment: The example folder is full of examples: https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/search?q=NewParquetReader (now I haven't ever used parquet so I don't know for sure whether or not you can actually make it work that way, but after a quick look at the code it seemed to me that that might be possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ReadByNumer`, make a slice of `[]ParquetProduct` with the desired length and use `Read`.

```
products := make([]ParquetProduct, r.cfg.RowsToRead) 
// ^ slice with length and capacity equal to r.cfg.RowsToRead
err = pr.Read(&products)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
```